# Automatically zoom to region of map where GPS traces appear and run TimeManager

Tags: qgis, timemanager

How would I accomplish in qgis automating of the production of multiple TimeManager recordings with a consistent orientation, zoom  and framing of gps traces?.

I expect it will involve python & postgis db queries but I've new to qgis and python so not sure where to start with setting orientations and framing a map layer or triggering TimeManager

For example suppose I have gps traces of events each with distinct start and end times taking place in different regions.

- Region A

  - Event 1
- Region B

  - Event 2
- Region C

  - Event 3

How can I use qgis & its TimeManager Plugin to automate the creation of the 3 events exports but setting the desired zoom etc to frame the recordings so they are all appear identical without requiring the user to manually pan and zoom to each event location and manually set up TimeManger? It would be great if it was able to react to new data entering a postgis db so that when event 4 was added it would process or at least prompt the user to see if it shold be processed

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not possible.

If you are able to provide a pull request to add the feature (and accompanying tests), please feel free to do so.